# How to change the color of last word appeared in breadcrumb

Tags: jquery, css

Below is the dynamically generated breadcrumb, now i want to show the last word i.e `hi man` as active by changing its color, how can i do this without changing anything in  block  ?

```
<span id="crumb">
   <a href="s">Tes 1</a>  &gt;&gt; 
   <a href="ogs/foods/541">Hello Boy</a> &gt;&gt; 
   <a href="d">hi man</a>
</span>


#crumb::a:last {
  color: #00f;
}
```

[Fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zht5j25/1/)

Comment: I would suggest not using `#00f` as the color of choice since it matches the default color of the `<a>` tag. Either way though, use `last-child` pseudo selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
#crumb a:last-child {
    /* style */
}
```

The double-colon syntax is used to identify pseudo-elements (`::before`/`::after`), not descendants; single-colons identify pseudo-classes, though `:last` is not a CSS selector (though Sizzle, and jQuery) implement such a selector.

References:

- [CSS selectors, level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Comment: I've been playing with CSS for quite a long time... ;) and you are, of course, absolutely welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `:last-child` selector.

**Example**

```
#crumb a:last-child {
    color: #00f;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/1zht5j25/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use pseudo elements (for IE8 and before it will not support) you can use the below jQuery snippet

```
$("#crumb:last-child").css("color", "red" );
```

Check these links for last-child browser support [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/), [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child)

Comment: Thanks  , but its always better to use css for fast performance

Comment: Yes, I totally agreed with that, its only a JS solution if you want to target browsers which don't support last-child pseudo class (read < IE8)